# SF Symbol imageView does not conform to pointSize?

Tags: ios, swift, sf-symbols

I have an empty UIImageView in my storyboard, and have the outlet in my ViewController.swift file. In viewDidLoad, I'm calling the below code:

```swift
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 50, weight: .light)
self.symbol.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar")
self.symbol.preferredSymbolConfiguration = config
```

The symbol loads fine, and even the weight is correctly reflected.

However, the size of the symbol image is still tied to the size of the UIImageView in the storyboard even though I have no constraints set on the UIImageView. And from what I can tell the pointSize declared in SymbolConfiguration has no effect on the size of the symbol image.

From what I can tell it seems that there are two ways to get pointSize in SF Symbols to work: 1. Do all of it programmatically or 2. do all of it in Storyboard / Inspector.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or does SF Symbols not support Storyboard + code configuration?

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler I just figured it out, you have to call sizeToFit() after setting the configuration. You'd think Apple would call it for you but I'm guessing they're having the developer call it to improve efficiency.

Comment: Dino, that's actually **wrong**.  (Repeating this for the sake of anyone googling here :) )  Using sizeToFit will only work in some limited situations.  The actual solution is very simple, and it's given by Rakuyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, you have to call `sizeToFit()` after setting the configuration. I'm guessing Apple left it for the dev to call it so that they could prevent unnecessary recalculation of UI sizing thus potentially improving efficiency.

Anyway, the solution is: call `sizeToFit()` on the UIImageView after setting the configuration.

Comment: Dino, that's actually **wrong**.  (Bold for the sake of anyone googling here :) )  Using sizeToFit will only work in some limited situations.  The actual solution is very simple, and it's given by Rakuyo.

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem by changing the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView` object to `.center`.

```swift
let imageView = UIImageView()

imageView.contentMode = .center // This is the key step.

imageView.preferredSymbolConfiguration = .init(pointSize: 10)
iconView.image = UIImage(systemName: "name")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this way instead:

```
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 50, weight: .light)
self.symbol.image = UIImage(systemName: "calendar", withConfiguration: config)
```

Comment: This is wrong.  See Rakuyo answer for the key step.